# WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet due to an exception

Tags: cxf, wildfly, wildfly-15

i want to deploy cxf-based application on wildfly17. i have not included external cxf library in war i want to use internal cxf of wildfly.?

server.log

```
2019-08-20 17:59:57,235 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\kumarkun\Downloads\jars\wildfly\wildfly-16.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
2019-08-20 17:59:57,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\kumarkun\Downloads\jars\wildfly\wildfly-16.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
2019-08-20 17:59:57,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "proj2.war" (runtime-name: "proj2.war")
2019-08-20 17:59:57,962 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
2019-08-20 17:59:58,058 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
2019-08-20 17:59:58,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2019-08-20 17:59:58,470 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
2019-08-20 17:59:58,658 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.7) 
2019-08-20 17:59:59,641 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2019-08-20 17:59:59,805 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2019-08-20 18:00:00,144 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.8.Final
2019-08-20 18:00:00,191 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.metadata] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS024061: Adding service endpoint metadata: id=com.services.Addition
 address=http://localhost:8080/proj2/AdditionService
 implementor=com.services.Addition
 serviceName={http://services.com/}AdditionService
 portName={http://services.com/}AdditionPort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
2019-08-20 18:00:00,230 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."proj2.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."proj2.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "proj2.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.WSFException: WFLYWS0066: Servlet class org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet declared in web.xml; either provide a proper deployment relying on JBossWS or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled.
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.tomcat.WebMetaDataModifier.configureEndpoints(WebMetaDataModifier.java:98)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.tomcat.WebMetaDataModifier.modify(WebMetaDataModifier.java:63)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.tomcat.WebMetaDataModifyingDeploymentAspect.start(WebMetaDataModifyingDeploymentAspect.java:40)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more

2019-08-20 18:00:00,739 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2019-08-20 18:00:00,939 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "proj2.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"proj2.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"proj2.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.WSFException: WFLYWS0066: Servlet class org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet declared in web.xml; either provide a proper deployment relying on JBossWS or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled."}}
2019-08-20 18:00:00,970 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "proj2.war" (runtime-name : "proj2.war")
2019-08-20 18:00:00,973 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."proj2.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "proj2.war"

2019-08-20 18:00:01,153 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2019-08-20 18:00:01,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2019-08-20 18:00:01,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2019-08-20 18:00:01,158 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 16.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 8.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 11390ms - Started 371 of 561 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 326 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

i tried to few solution:
 1) comment out:-

standalone.xml

```
 <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.webservices.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
```

2)
adding dependencies in MAINFIST.MF

Dependencies: org.apache.cxf services

Addition.java :-

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://services.com/", portName = "AdditionPort", serviceName = "AdditionService")
public class Addition {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "func1", action = "urn:Func1")
    public int func1(@WebParam(name = "arg0") int x, @WebParam(name = "arg1") int y) {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

web.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>proj1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

cxf-bean.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://services.com/"
        id="addition" implementor="com.services.Addition"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/addition.wsdl" endpointName="tns:AdditionPort"
        serviceName="tns:AdditionService" address="/AdditionPort">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" scope="singleton" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

applicationConext.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties"/>
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- Imports SpringMVC configuration -->
    <import resource="cxf-beans.xml" />
</beans>
```

i expect to deploy cxf based applicaion on wildfly server using wildfly internal modules.